# Ubuntu Software Center Error: Failed to lock the package manager

Tags: 10.10, installation, apt, update-manager, updates

Ever since I installed Ubuntu 10.10 I've been getting this error when trying to install ANYTHING via software center and have only been able to install software via Synaptic and apt-get. I 'm sure neither Synaptic or aptitude are running. What is this?

[image]

Comment: I'm glad that it worked ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like apt-get are running so paste this on terminal to stop it before using Software Center:

```
sudo killall apt-get
```